# How to get the announcer badge and what does share a link mean?

Tags: support, badges

I have a simple question. What does

> Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

for announcer badge means?

Answer (score 6):

Under every question/answer, there is a "share" link:

[image: Share link]

The last part of this link is your user ID. If you share this link, and if someone clicks on it, the system will know that you shared this link (because of the user ID indicator). If this link is visited by 25 unique IP addresses, you get the Announcer badge.